# Cytoscape Error Loading KEGG Pathway Index Out of Bounds for length 1

Tags: cytoscape

I'm trying to use CytoKegg in Cytoscape to overlay data on a KEGG Pathway. After uploading the KGML file from KEGG, depending on which pathway, I'm either 1) Not getting the Cytoscape app to interact or 2) Receiving this error message: Error Loading KEGG Pathway Index Out of Bounds for length 1.

I have previously successfully used the macaque WNT & Melanogenesis pathways but am now having #2 occur with these pathways. I'd like to use the Hedgehog pathway and am having #1 happen. The only thing that has changed on my end since successfully doing this is I'm currently out of the US -- I don't think this would affect this app or KEGG but I'm not sure what else would have changed.

Any help is greatly appreciated so thanks in advance!!!

Comment: Greetings.  Sorry to hear about the problems you're seeing.  You don't mention which version of Cytoscape or CytoKegg your are using, so I'll assume you are using the latest of each.  Error number 2 is clearly a bug somewhere.  Can you try running Cytoscape from the console?  You should see a Java backtrace, which will show us the actual source of the bug and help us fix it.

Answer (score 0):

You could try contacting the App authors listed on this page to see if they can help: https://apps.cytoscape.org/apps/cykeggparser
and if that fails there is another Cytoscape App that can import KGML files: https://apps.cytoscape.org/apps/keggscape

chris